# App crashing with exception: *** Collection was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, crash

App crashing with exception:

```
 *** Collection  was mutated while being enumerated.
2016-01-25 08:55:30.606 Mink Chatter[416:70120] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection  was mutated while being enumerated.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1821c5900 0x181833f80 0x1821c5334 0x186ead9f0 0x186ead7d8 0x186ead6d8 0x1001a6834 0x10015ddc0 0x100905bf0 0x100905bb0 0x100914e10 0x1009144d8 0x181e2d470 0x181e2d020)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Code:

```
self.refreshIndicators = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    UIView *indicator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.height)];
    float delay = 0.4 * i;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];

    [self addSubview:indicator];
    [self.refreshIndicators addObject:indicator];
}
```

Comment: provide some code to determine the problem.

Comment: self.refreshIndicators = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        UIView *indicator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.height)];
        float delay = 0.4 * i;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];
        [self addSubview:indicator];
        [self.refreshIndicators addObject:indicator];
    }

Comment: Update your question. Don't put your code in comments.

Comment: @viratpuar If you are going to edit a post, please do it properly by formatting it as needed.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code causing the crash?  Set an exception. Teak point to confirm. What is the purpose of the uiview animation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you enumerate some object, for example, NSMutableArray or NSMutableSet, using for-loop (for (id _obj in object)) and in that loop removing or adding some objects to the same object. It is not possible and causes exception.

Try this:
Keep your code in below loop.

```
@synchronized(self)
  {
       // your code goes here 
  }
```

Hope this helps.